# Converting cURL to Python Requests

Tags: python, api, curl

I need to convert the following cURL command to python requests.

```
curl 'https://test.com/api/v1/courses/xx/discussion_topics/xx/entries.json' \
 -F 'message=<message>' \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
```

So far I have `requests.post("https://test.com/api/v1/courses/xx/discussion_topics/xx/entries")`
but how do I add the message and auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 requests.post("https://test.com/api/v1/courses/xx/discussion_topics/xx/entries.json, data=json.dumps({"message": "<message>"}), headers={"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"})
```