# Convert mailchimp curl request to python request

Tags: python, authentication, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am able to run curl successfully but not worked with python request for mailchimp API.It gives an error `like urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

CURL

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists' \
--user 'anystring:6a983664930fc8ba1eecdsdf334344f40-us9' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"name":"My test","contact":{"company":"Cool","address1":"Awesome place","city":"Lanka","state":"MH","zip":"43472","country":"IN","phone":""},"permission_reminder":"You'\''re receiving this email because you signed up.","campaign_defaults":{"from_name":"VD","from_email":"hey@sdfsdf.com","subject":"","language":"en"},"email_type_option":true}' \
--include
```

Python request :

```
import urllib2
import json
import requests
url = 'https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'

all_params={"user":"my_username:6a983664930fc8ba1eecd1d5d68f4f40-us9",
           "name":"My test",
           "contact":{"company":"Cool","address1":"Awesome place","city":"Lanka","state":"MH","zip":"43472","country":"IN","phone":""},"permission_reminder":"You'\''re receiving this email because you signed up.","campaign_defaults":{"from_name":"VD","from_email":"hey@sdfsdf.com","subject":"","language":"en"},
           "email_type_option":'true'}

post_data = urllib2.quote(json.dumps(all_params))
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, post_data, headers) 
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

I have referred [Converting cURL to Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426731/converting-curl-to-python-requests) but not worked.

Comment: Are you trying to use [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/)?  Your title says requests, and you import requests, but then your code doesn't use it and instead uses urllib2.

Comment: I have tried both bot did not work. This is code with urllib2.

Comment: @VigneshPrajapati I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution or some workaround?

Comment: hi @giliev , I had solved it. It was problem of URL with data center. I was using us9.api... instead of https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists because my account was created under us6. So, you need to match data center with your URL in request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved it. It was problem of URL with data center. I was using us9.api... instead of us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists because my account was created under us6. So, I need to use data center where my account is registered with my URL in request.